Solana decode info from system program
I have a problem with decoding info from LPMint.
I'm working with Dex aggregator now and I need to parse market info.
So, now from market I receive lpMint info with address '11111111111111111111111111111111' - I suppose this is a system program.
From LpMintAccount I have this data,
  data: new Uint8Array([115, 111, 108, 97, 110, 97, 95, 115, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 95, 112, 114, 111, 103, 114, 97, 109]),
  executable: true,
  lamports: 1,
  owner: {
    _bn: {
      negative: 0,
      words: [
        0,
        44417248,
        284105,
        45604247,
        22257789,
        35793532,
        50406772,
        43032766,
        12522635,
        90593,
        0,
      ],
      length: 10,
      red: null,
    },
  },
  rentEpoch: 18446744073709552000,
  space: 21,
}

When I try to parse it via SPL_MINT_LAYOUT.decode(lpMintAccount.data) - it throws an error  The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 20. Received 44

I looked at the SPL_MINT_LAYOUT layout and it has these values:
```export const SPL_MINT_LAYOUT = struct([
  u32('mintAuthorityOption'),
  publicKey('mintAuthority'),
  u64('supply'),
  u8('decimals'),
  u8('isInitialized'),
  u32('freezeAuthorityOption'),
  publicKey('freezeAuthority'),
])

I understand, that the incoming data is more, that that struct, but how can I get the right format?

The full code is

```const account = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id));

  if (account === null) throw Error(' get id info error ');

  const info = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(account.data);

  const marketId = info.marketId;

  const lpMint = info.lpMint;

  const [marketAccount, lpMintAccount] = await Promise.all([
    await connection.getAccountInfo(marketId),
    await connection.getAccountInfo(lpMint),
  ]);

  if (marketAccount === null) throw Error(' get market info error');

  const marketInfo = MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(marketAccount.data);

  const b = new PublicKey(lpMint).toString();

  if (lpMintAccount === null) throw Error(' get lp mint info error');

  const lpMintInfo2 = SPL_MINT_LAYOUT.decode(lpMintAccount.data);


Thanks!

